# Table design when one data is dependant of another and the second one has repeated values

Tags: database-design, referential-integrity

I have a products, and subproducts.

Like:

```
Product Identifier - Product Name - Subproduct Identifier - SubProduct Name
                 1       ProA              1                   SubProA1
                 1       ProA              2                   SubProA2
                 1       ProA              3                   SubProA3
                 2       ProB              1                   SubProB1
                 2       ProB              2                   SubProB2
                 2       ProB              3                   SubProB3
                 3       ProC              1                   SubProC1
                 3       ProC              2                   SubProC2
                 3       ProC              3                   SubProC3
```

As you can see, the subproduct identifier is not unique. My input is gonna be the product and the subproduct, and I need to return the names.

I did this:

> Table Products: ID, Name
>
> Table SubProducts: IDproduct, IDsubProduct, Name

But I *know* that is wrong, I wanted to make 3 tables, products, subproducts and a relation between the two, but I don't know how to design it.

If I was to save the product and subproduct into another table, I would have to save both values, that table would have to have the productID and subproductID columns, that's why I feel having a relation product subproduct table would be the best.

But I'm having a hard time doing it.

Comment: Do you also have sub-subproducts (subproducts of subproducts of products)? And sub-sub-subproducts?

Comment: Can something be a subproduct of 2 or more different products?

Comment: No, to both questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the clarifications in your comments, that there are only 2 levels of products, e.g. only `Products` and `SubProducts` and no subproduct is related to two or more products, your design is fine.

I would only add two unique constraints on table `SubProducts`, on `(IDproduct, IDsubProduct)` and on `(IDproduct, Name)` - or make one of them `PRIMARY KEY` and the other `UNIQUE`:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
( IDproduct INT NOT NULL
, Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

, CONSTRAINT Products_PK
      PRIMARY KEY (IDproduct)
, CONSTRAINT Product_Name_UQ
      UNIQUE (Name)
) ;


CREATE TABLE SubProducts
( IDproduct INT NOT NULL
, IDsubProduct INT NOT NULL
, Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

, CONSTRAINT SubProducts_PK
      PRIMARY KEY (IDproduct, IDsubProduct)
, CONSTRAINT SubProduct_Name_UQ
      UNIQUE (IDproduct, Name)
, CONSTRAINT Products_SubProducts_FK
      FOREIGN KEY (IDproduct)
      REFERENCES Products (IDproduct)
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A hierarchical relationship is probably fine:

```
PRODUCT
id
name
parent_id (nullable)

insert into product values (1, 'Proc A');

insert into product values (2, 'SubProA1', 1);
```

For performance reasons, you will need special queries. I'd use postgres over mysql if I were you. Use WITH queries.